# Stagger divs vertically

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to display divs in a staggered vertical arrangement like this image?

[image]

So far I have used Flexbox to get close but can't stagger the rows because I don't want to pre-determine how many circles are in each row, I want the user's browser width to control how many circles are per row (hence no classes or childs on the circle divs).

As the user's browser gets narrower, I want the circles to respond so that in a mobile size they would become 1 long single column.

[Here is a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gq261bsy/) to show the code so far. I'd be open to JQuery if needed.
Thank you for any help.

```css
* {margin: 0; padding: 0;}
body {font-family: Helvetica Neue; font-style: normal; text-align: center; color: #111;}

section {width: 100%; display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
.memoji_list {display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; flex-direction: row;}
.memoji {background:  green; border-radius:999px; width:100px; height:100px; margin: 0 auto;}
```

```html
<body>
  
<section>
  <div class="memoji_list">
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>

  </div>
</section>

</body>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick I made for [hexagon shapes](https://css-tricks.com/hexagons-and-beyond-flexible-responsive-grid-patterns-sans-media-queries/) can be applied here:

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  --s: 100px; /* the circle size */
  --m: 8px;   /* control the distance between circles */
  --vc: 10px; /* control the distance between rows */
  
  --f: calc(2*var(--s) + 4*var(--m) - 2*var(--vc) - 2px);
}

.container {
  font-size: 0; 
}

.container div {
  width: var(--s);
  margin: var(--m);
  height: var(--s);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: initial;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:red;
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--m) - var(--vc));
}

.container::before {
  content: "";
  width: calc(var(--s)/2 + var(--m));
  float: left;
  height: 120%; 
  shape-outside: repeating-linear-gradient(#0000 0 calc(var(--f) - 3px),#000 0 var(--f));
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="container">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Jeepers! Yeah that's exactly it. I was thinking this was a very long shot but you nailed it. The Hexagon article was amazing to read too. What is the Browser compatibility for this though I'm curious.

Comment: @Antistandard the browser support should be good, it covers all the major browsers. You can replace the variable and the calculation with the final value if you want better support (you can get rid of calc() and CSS variables)

Comment: Well, thank you so much Temani, that's some nice code. The variables are sweet. If I have problems I'll use hard values rather than the Calc and vars like you mentioned. But thanks again, this is great work.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.row{
   display:flex;
   justify-content:space-evenly;
   flex-direction:row;
   
   }
   
   .memoji{
   width:100px;
   height:100px;
   background-color:green;
   border-radius:50%;
   }
```

```html
<div class='row'>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
     </div>
     <div class='row'> 
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
     <div class='row'> 
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not responsive (and you have to enlarge the snippet window to "full page" size in order to get the amount of elements into the rows that you have in your image), but it's a starting point, using a `max-width` and `margin: 0 auto` for the container and a `margin-left` for `.memoji:nth-child(11n - 4)`

You could then use media queries to have different amounts of circles depending on the window width, with similar rules.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Helvetica Neue;
  font-style: normal;
  text-align: center;
  color: #111;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.memoji_list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.memoji {
  background: green;
  border-radius: 999px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin: 10px;
}

.memoji:nth-child(11n - 4) {
  margin-left: 70px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section>
    <div class="memoji_list">
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
      <div class="memoji">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```