# css - how to use grid with different number of item in a row

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

This is my current UI.
[image]

This is what I want to make for the grid-item.

```
    1   2
  3   4   5
    6   7
```

How can I do it?

App.js

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container">
        <div className="item">1</div>
        <div className="item">2</div>
        <div className="item">3</div>
        <div className="item">4</div>
        <div className="item">5</div>
        <div className="item">6</div>
        <div className="item">7</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

style.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px 12px;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
}

.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Codesandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-meadow-zxclh?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70253471/8620333

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A grid by definition has a set number of columns. What you can do though is defined a multiple of columns and apply a "column-span" rule to specific divs using [grid-column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-column).

> ### grid-column
>
> The **`grid-column`** CSS shorthand property specifies a grid item's
> size and location within a grid column by contributing a line, a span,
> or nothing (automatic) to its grid placement, thereby specifying the
> inline-start and inline-end edge of its grid area.

Example uses 6 columns and each div spans either 2 or 3 columns to get the correct elements "per row". You can tweak the styles/layouts from here.

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px 12px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, auto);
  justify-items: center;
}
```

JSX

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: 'span 3' }}>1</div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: 'span 3' }}>2</div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: 'span 2' }}>3</div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: 'span 2' }}>4</div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: 'span 2' }}>5</div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: 'span 3' }}>6</div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: 'span 3' }}>7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Edit css-how-to-use-grid-with-different-number-of-item-in-a-row]

[image]
[image]

You could even explicitly express the grid tracks you want them to be laid out on.

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "2/4" }}>
      1
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "4/6" }}>
      2
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "1/3" }}>
      3
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "3/5" }}>
      4
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "5/7" }}>
      5
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "2/4" }}>
      6
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "4/6" }}>
      7
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

On a 5-track grid, so you don't need to "center" between tracks.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(5, auto);
```

...

```
<div className="App">
  <div className="container">
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "2" }}>
      1
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "4" }}>
      2
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "1" }}>
      3
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "3" }}>
      4
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "5" }}>
      5
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "2" }}>
      6
    </div>
    <div className="item" style={{ gridColumn: "4" }}>
      7
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]
[image]

Hopefully by this point it is more clear how to use the grid tracks to layout content where you like.

Comment: can make other items closer to `4`?

Comment: @CCCC Do you mean items 1, 2, 6, and 7? Yes, I added a more explicit track layout that "centers" 1, 2, 6, and 7 between 3, 4, and 5.

Answer (score 0):

By changing a little bit your `HTML` structure, I have what you are looking for. At least I think:

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
}
.row {
  display: grid;
  gap: 5rem;
}
.row:nth-child(1),
.row:nth-child(3) {
  grid-template-columns: auto auto;
  justify-content: center;
}
.row:nth-child(2) {
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 5rem;
}
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item">3</div>
      <div class="item">4</div>
      <div class="item">5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="item">6</div>
      <div class="item">7</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it necessary that `.container` is `display: grid`?

Comment: No, I added it to have some gap between my `rows`. I could use `margin`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I see

Answer (score 0):

you can use `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` for a box having `display: flex;`

This will automatically adjust the alignment and put the content in the center of the box.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: grey;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container > div {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 1px;
  padding: 1px 10px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>  
  <div>4</div>  
</div>
<div class="flex-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the bootstrap inbuilt classes.

Step-1 : Just add the bootstrap CDN link to  inedx.html from here

```
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
```

Step-2 : Use this classes

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="container p-4 text-center">
        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-evenly ">
          <div className="item col-6">1</div>
          <div className="item col-6">2</div>
        </div>
        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-evenly ">
          <div className="item col-4">3</div>
          <div className="item col-4">4</div>
          <div className="item col-4">5</div>
        </div>
        <div className="row d-flex justify-content-evenly ">
          <div className="item col-6">6</div>
          <div className="item col-6">7</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Step-3 And use this `style.css`

```
.item {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

**If `justify-content-evenly` doesn't work , you can try `justify-content-around`.**

[image]

Answer (score -3):

Use bootstrap for grid.
It has classes for rows and column. I will make it easy